# How to encypt/decrypt messages after ECDH key agreement

Tags: encryption, diffie-hellman

I am using Diffie-Helman key exchange to generate the shared secret. But how will can a message be encrypted using this shared key?

Comment: Why did you tag this with PQ-crypto? Diffie-Hellman is not PQ secure, neither on finite fields, not on elliptic curves.

Answer (score 4):

You can't encrypt a message with ECDH alone, because all it gives you is a shared secret that you can't really control. Rather, you use that secret in a symmetric scheme like AES (generally after passing it through a KBKDF to convert from an ECDH result to a proper-length and less-structured symmetric key, which you then use as the key for symmetric crypto).

Comment: my shared secret is a point(x,y) which is not 256 or 32 bits long. how can i use AES in such a scenario?

Comment: @rahul That's where the KBKDF comes in. For instance, with TLS, the premaster secret is the x-coordinate of the point. You then pass this to a KBKDF like [HKDF](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5869) to get the actual key.

Comment: Note that you need to provide for integrity/authenticity if you want to send the ciphertext over an insecure channel. You could for instance use the resulting AES key in GCM mode of operation.